# Build project with gluon, cannot files com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, gluon

I want to install my GluonProject on an android device. 
If I used the following gradle, I will received the following error message:

**ErrorMessage**

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':schoolChecksApp:androidRuntimeCopy'.
> Could not find support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/25.1.1/support-media-compat-25.1.1.aar
> Could not find support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core-utils/25.1.1/support-core-utils-25.1.1.aar
> Could not find support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-compat/25.1.1/support-compat-25.1.1.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Could not find support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.1.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/25.1.1/support-media-compat-25.1.1.aar

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

**gradle.build**

```
version '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 8
targetCompatibility = 8

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.12'
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.school.School'

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '3.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '3.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '3.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:ignite-spring:1.0.2'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.6.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '4.2.0.Final'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.12'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-xjc', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1'
    compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.23.4'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '5.3.6.Final'
    compile group: 'org.apache.log4j', name: 'com.springsource.org.apache.log4j', version: '1.2.16'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.8'
    compile group: 'com.owlike', name: 'genson', version: '0.99'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey.contribs', name: 'jersey-apache-client', version: '1.8'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-client', version: '1.8'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-server', version: '1.8'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-core', version: '1.8'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-servlet', version: '1.8'

    compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.+'
    compile group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "7.36.0"
    compile 'com.gluonhq:particle:1.1.3'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'


    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.1')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'

    testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-core:4.0.16-alpha"
    testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-junit5:4.0.16-alpha"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5"
    testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-spock:4.0.16-alpha"
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.13.2'
}


jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'push-notifications', 'runtime-args', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        compileSdkVersion = '24'
        androidSdk ="C:\\Users\\U1\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk"
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}


jfx {
    // minimal requirement for jfxNative-task
    appName = "School"
    mainClass = 'com.school.school'
    vendor = 'school'
}
```

But if I add the lib
**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'**
I will receive the same error (and I cannot build the application anymore because I received the message that the module is not specified).

Comment: Update to latest jfxmobile plugin 1.3.18 and try again?

Comment: I have still the same error